# Some insight on Object key accessing in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im just alittle curious, as well as a bit confused.  In my lua code im setting a new object like so from the start.

```
enemy = {};

enemy.__index = enemy;

function enemy.new(args)
Obj = {};
setmetatable(Obj,enemy);
Obj.name = "bullet";
Obj.x = args.x;
Obj.y = args.y;
Obj.spriteTexFile= "Invader.png";
Obj.sprite = display.newImage( Obj.spriteTexFile);
Obj.sprite:setReferencePoint ( display.TopLeftReferencePoint );
Obj.sprite.x = Obj.x;
Obj.sprite.y = Obj.y;
Obj.sprite.alpha = 0;
Obj.health = 100;
Obj.activeBul = false;
Obj.bullet = Bullet.new({x=Obj.sprite.x,y=Obj.sprite.y});
return Obj;
end
...
return enemy;
end
```

So when instantiating a new Enemy obj I call the new function above.  NOW in the same file, a function in the Enemy Object I have the following function for example which allows me to acces the "self.bullet", a Bullet Object created when the Enemy is created.  It also allows me to call the function trajectBullet in this Bullet instants.

```
function enemy:shoot()
local Bullet = require "Bullet";
local DEFAULTTIME = 5;--Movement time per space
    self.bullet:trajectBullet({x=self.sprite.x,y=display.contentHeight, time =
                               DEFAULTTIME*display.contentHeight-self.sprite.y)});
end
```

My Question comes with a call like the following.  If I try setting a property of a Bullet in this case, the owner property, i get a nil error and wont let me change it.  If someone could help me understand alittle how accessing keys and properties really works that would help me out alot.

```
function enemy:setBulletOwner()
self.bullet.owner = self;
end
```

---

UPDATE:

```
bullet = {};

bullet.__index = bullet;

function bullet.new(arg)
local Obj = {};
setmetatable ( Obj, bullet );
Obj.sprite = display.newRect(  0, 0, 3, 7 );
Obj.sprite.x = arg.x;
Obj.sprite.y = arg.y;
Obj.sprite:setFillColor ( 255, 255, 255  );
Obj.sprite:setReferencePoint ( display.TopLeftReferencePoint );
Obj.owner = nil;
return Obj;
end

function bullet:trajectBullet(arg)
self.sprite.tween = transition.to(self.sprite,{ tansistion = easing.outExpo, y = arg.y,         x=arg.x,time= arg.time,onComplete = function() bullet:cancelTween(self.sprite); 
    self.owner.sprite:dispatchEvent( {name = "canShootAgain"} ); end}); 
end
```

Keep in mind Obj.owner should be getting set from the function below.

```
function enemy:setBulletOwner()
print("BULLET MADE");
self.bullet.owner = self;
end
```

Comment: Probably, you are executing `enemy.setBulletOwner()` instead of `enemy:setBulletOwner()`

Comment: no im executing enemy:setBulletOwner()

Comment: You forgot to add the **full** error message. There are various types of `"nil"` error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have your classes set up like this

**Bullet**

```
Bullet = {}
Bullet_mt = { __index = Bullet }

function Bullet:new(co_ordinates)
    local obj = {x=co_ordinates[1],y=co_ordinates[2]}
    obj.owner = "You" --etc...
    return setmetatable(obj,Bullet_mt)
end
```

**Enemy**

```
Enemy = {slogan="Gettm!'"}
Enemy_mt = {__index = Enemy;}

function Enemy:new(args)
    local obj = {}
    --etc..
    obj.bullet = Bullet:new({0,0})
    return setmetatable(obj,Enemy_mt)
    --alert return setmetatable(obj,getmetatable(self))
end

function Enemy:getBulletOwner()
    return self.bullet.owner;
end
```

You shouldn't be requiring "Bullet" each time the enemy shoots in `enemy:shoot`. When you want to create a bullet for an enemy if you only want the enemy to have one bullet you should
create a new '*instance*' of the bullet class and associate it with the key `bullet` like you've been doing `obj.bullet= Bullet.new(...)` but also introduce this functionality into a method of `Enemy` (so you can add a new bullet after the old one goes out of range etc...).

---

If a index doesn't exist within a table, it will go looking for the index in the table associated with `__index` in the metatable assigned to the table in question. As an example say `a = Enemy:new()`, and we wanted to find out the slogan of the enemy, via `a.slogan` we would look for the index `slogan` in `a` but not find it. So we would then go check what `__index` was associated with in the metatable of `a`, in this case `Enemy`. So we look for `slogan` in `Enemy`, it exists so we end up with `"Gettm!'".

Adding the following code beneath the class definitions

```
en = Enemy:new()
print(en:getBulletOwner())
print(en.slogan)
```

Produces

```
You
Gettm!'
```

---

Also be weary of the difference between `a:b(arg1,arg2)` and `a.b(arg1,arg2)`. `a:b(arg1,arg2)` is essentially equivalent to `a.b(a,arg1,arg2)` where `a` is bound to `self` within the function. An example of this would be:

```
print(en.getBulletOwner())
```

produces

```
lua: l.lua:22: attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)
```

while

```
print(en:getBulletOwner())
```

produces

```
You
```

Comment: Thank you for the all the information you posted first off.  Im reading your post and to me it looks like im doing the same thing you are in your first section.  in a function of enemy i try doing "self.bullet.owner" like that you did in your getBulletOwner and I get " attempt to index field 'bullet'(a nil value)"  I know the reason why is because self.bullet is itself =to nil, WHEN IT FACT IT SHOULDNT!!! so its trying to access information from a nil so it crashes.  I just am confused as to what im doing wrong.  I updated my original post to include the bullet new

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty try change `bullet.__index = bullet;` to `bullet.__index = function(_,key) return bullet[key] end`